Stacking Postgres function calls
I have 3 functions that work fine when I manually trigger them in my console but times out or hangs when I run them together. The functions are all dependent on each other, as example:

createA - creates table A, indexes table A
createB - from table A, creates Table B and indexes Table B
createC - from table B, creates Table C and indexes Table C

Example of the function (all 3 functions have the similar layout)
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION createB()
RETURNS VOID AS
$$
BEGIN

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tableB CASCADE;

WITH
temp_working as NOT MATERIALIZED
(SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE type <> 'tainted')

CREATE TABLE tableB AS
select * from (
    SELECT
    dept, dest, price, plane from temp_working x inner join temp_working y
        on x.plane <> y.plane and
           x.dest = y.dest

    UNION 
    
    SELECT
    dept, dest, price, plane from temp_working x inner join temp_working y
        on x.plane = y.plane and
           x.dest = y.dest) x

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_1 ON tableB USING btree (dept, dest, price, plane);

END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

All 3 functions involve creating a table and then indexes it so that the next function can perform optimally with the indexes. The weird problem is when I run all through 3 functions together in a single statement, it hangs or timeouts.
set statement_timeout as '180s'
select createA();
select createB(); -- idles here
select createC();

But it works fine when I first run:
select createA() -- success
and then followed by select createB() -- success
There also should not be any locks as each function creates their own table and is consumed by the next function. What is bothering me is that it does not seem to be working when they are passed as a single statement but works if they are separate. Current findings:

There does not seem to be any lock on the queries via pg_stat_activity
All code in the functions work well when they are not wrapped in a function
The end-to-end completion of each function averages about 3 minutes for each function
Postgres version - 15.1.1.19

Is there any side-effects when running them as a single? What else can I try to pinpoint the root issue?

"Creating an index can interfere with regular operation of a database. Normally PostgreSQL locks the table to be indexed against writes and performs the entire index build with a single scan of the table" ... "PostgreSQL supports building indexes without locking out writes...."  Please read the rest of the documentation here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html#:~:text=PostgreSQL%20supports%20building%20indexes%20without%20locking%20out%20writes

I understand that it might be, but the indexes are created before the next function call. Does that hint that it is created but not fully built?

Why do you have a CREATE TABLE tableB AS.... in your createA() function?

Typo, edit made. The create index should anyway complete within the function before moving on to the next function call. Also tried that concurrent does not work in functions.

What version of Postgres? Why not use stored procedures? In any case, if those tables should be created together, do you get the same hangup when just creating the tables/indexes in 1 statement, outside of your function?

a statement like SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE....  Can, and will, use the INDEX ONLY AFTER it is being created.     Running those 3 function (which seems to depend on each other)  should be done sequentially because of this dependency .

@Zack, updated with version. Procedures are similar to functions anyways, doubt it will make a difference. Split because of troubleshooting. @Luuk I agree, the table A that createB is using is already indexed.

What you describe as a single statement is not a single statement.  Also, it has syntax error, missing semicolon between 1st and 2nd lines.

I would at least add ANALYZE to the code, right after creating the indexes.

The query run by createB is happening immediately after createA finishes, which means the just-created table has not yet been analyzed (because autovacuum takes some time to launch and then get to it).  This can lead to horrific plans.  You should insert a manual ANALYZE command when you need to use a table immediately after populating it.
When you run the functions separately, perhaps you are waiting long enough between them that autovacuum does it thing.  Or maybe not, we can't tell from your description exactly how you are doing it. But I'd say the lack of statistics is guilty until proven innocent here.

Thanks, its the immediate functions that caused the issues. Adding VACUUM ANALYZE <table> solved it.
